How to handle issues related to dynamic web elements while doing UI automation using Selenium
I am using Selenium framework using Java to automate testing for our web application. The web application has a UI and I was able to automate the UI tests using Selenium. We used xpaths and web elements to automate the UI tests.
However, after every new build, the developer changes the web elements and xpaths on the UI, and hence my automation fails because Selenium can't find the web elements and xpaths which we previously used to automate the tests.
How do I tackle this issue. Is there a good practice to handle a situation where I can avoid this situation?

If the webpage DOM is being changed frequently by Dev, then I would call it out as the application is not stable and perform automation after the stability is acquired. Or this situation wouldn't change, where you need to keep adjusting the locators as per the dev's changes. This is more of a process-related issue in my view.

On the other hand, if your automation is an in-sprint one, where the dev and tester would work simultaneously, then this kind of re-work is expected to an extent, again, depends on the volume of tests at hand. In-sprint shouldn't have many tests, and the current in-sprint tests should become stable and a subset would go into regression for the next sprint, and so the cycle continues. But as I said, you need to check it from a process-perspective. This is my opinion

You should talk to the developers to convince them they provide stable ids, instead of generated, essentially random, ids, or otherwise provide additional names/data-attributes so you can easily find elements, even if they move around or the structure changes.

It sounds like you need better parity between your testing levels.  Like  @MarkRotteveel mentioned, it's a hard task but convincing all of your engineering to care about that kind of thing, is imperative.
